# Azure Devops with Data Factory - ##[error]Access to the path 'D:\a\r1\a\_myDrop\drop' is denied

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I am creating a release pipeline.
As per Microsoft documentation, I am using their pre and post deployment powershell script.

On creating the Azure PowerShell task, I created an "Azure Service Connection" with creator permissions on the destination resource group.

I am now getting the following error when the PowerShell script task is run in the pipeline:

```
##[error]Access to the path 'D:\a\r1\a\_myDrop\drop' is denied
```

[image]

I am unsure what additional permissions may be required and would appreciate any expertise.

Comment: Can you link to the specific article you’ve followed please? Is this that business with pausing the triggers before deploying?

Comment: This is the folder on which you publish your artifacts on the build agent. Do you use a private agent pool? Are you on the same time inside this folder? I get this error some times when I have the specific directory opened on a file explorer on the build agent.

Comment: @wBob : the article is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery

about half way down, in the section "best practices for CI/CD:

Pre- and post-deployment script. Before the Resource Manager deployment step in CI/CD, you need to complete certain tasks, like stopping and restarting triggers and performing cleanup. We recommend that you use PowerShell scripts before and after the deployment task. For more information, see Update active triggers. The data factory team has provided a script to use located at the bottom of this page.

Comment: @GeralexGR :

Im not sure what a private pool is, but i dont think i am using one. I used a build agent to create the drop and am now pointing the release agent to the drop location.

Comment: @GeralexGR :

Update: The Agent Pool is "Azure Pipelines" and the Agent Specification is "Windows Latest"

Answer (score 0):

Consider below Unsupported features

•   By design, Data Factory doesn't allow cherry-picking of commits or selective publishing of resources. Publishes will include all changes made in the data factory.

- Data factory entities depend on each other. For example, triggers depend on pipelines, and pipelines depend on datasets and other pipelines. Selective publishing of a subset of resources could lead to unexpected behaviors and errors.
- On rare occasions when you need selective publishing, consider using a hotfix. For more information, see Hotfix production environment.

•   The Azure Data Factory team doesn’t recommend assigning Azure RBAC controls to individual entities (pipelines, datasets, etc.) in a data factory. For example, if a developer has access to a pipeline or a dataset, they should be able to access all pipelines or datasets in the data factory. If you feel that you need to implement many Azure roles within a data factory, look at deploying a second data factory.

•   You can't publish from private branches.

•   You can't currently host projects on Bitbucket.

•   You can't currently export and import alerts and matrices as parameters.

•   In the code repository under the adf_publish branch, a folder named 'PartialArmTemplates' is currently added beside the 'linkedTemplates' folder, 'ARMTemplateForFactory.json' and 'ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json' files as part of publishing with source control.

Refer official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery#unsupported-features)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when following this [tutorial](https://iterationinsights.com/article/azure-data-factory-ci-cd-with-devops-pipelines/#Building-the-Release-Pipeline-UAT-Stage).

I solved that by fixing the `armTemplate` path argument in the `Azure PowerShell script: Pre-Deployment` agent job. In my case, it as missing the `/ARMTemplateForFactory.json` part from the path.

So, instead of

```
-armTemplate "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Azure Data Factory-CI/drop" -ResourceGroupName $(ResourceGroup) -DataFactoryName $(DataFactory) -predeployment $true -deleteDeployment $false
```

I used:

```
-armTemplate "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Azure Data Factory-CI/drop/ARMTemplateForFactory.json" -ResourceGroupName $(ResourceGroup) -DataFactoryName $(DataFactory) -predeployment $true -deleteDeployment $false
```